# Сохранения большого кол-ва данных в xml PYTHON

Tags: python, xml

Имеется данный сайт с объявлениями(https://kvartiry-bolgarii.ru/) Со всех объявлений нужно забрать всю информацию (картинки, описание, цена и т.д.), к примеру с этого (https://kvartiry-bolgarii.ru/neveroyatnaya-kvartira-s-vidom-na-more-tip-pentkhaus-o26253)

Сбор всех данных работает, однако наполнение xml файла не удается в полной мере. Т.к. скрипт за место того чтобы информацию из каждого объявления записывать друг за другом, он заменяет данные из первого объявления, данными из второго объявления.

Xml файл должен иметь примерно такой вид

```
<items>
   <item>
      <id>1</id>
      <price> 1700 </price>
   </item>
   <item>
      <id>2</id>
      <prive> 500 </price>
   </item>
</items>
```

P.s. извиняюсь за то что закинул весь код, с частью выше комментария перед обработкой для xml никаких проблем нет.

Вопрос в том, как можно реализовать записать данных каждой страницы, поместив данные в конце xml в теге
`<item> ...  </item>`

Код который использую на данный момент.
Получение xml начинается после: (  # ↓ Putting information in xml ↓  ):

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from xml.etree import ElementTree


options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
options.add_experimental_option("useAutomationExtension", False)
options.add_argument("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled")

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.159 Safari/537.36"
}



def get_link_info():
    number = 0
    all_links = []

    try:
        url = "https://kvartiry-bolgarii.ru"
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(
            executable_path=r'C:\Users\kk\Desktop\scrap_house\drivers\chromedriver.exe',
            options=options
        )

        driver.get(url)

        time.sleep(3)
        old_links = set()  # Empty Set

        tr = True

        while tr:
            # Scroll to get more ads
            driver.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0,3825)", "")
            # Wait for new ads to load
            time.sleep(5)
            links_divs = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="content"]//a')  # Find Elements
            ans = set(links_divs) - set(old_links)  # Remove old elements
            for link in ans:
                # Scroll to the link.
                driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", link)
                fir = link.get_attribute('href')
                all_links.append(fir)
            # Remove Duplicates
            old_links = links_divs
            #tr = False

            for finale_link in all_links:
                check = "https://kvartiry-bolgarii.ru/kvartira-v-elitnom-komplekse-s-unikalynym-sadom-o21751"

                if finale_link == check:
                    print("Завершено: ", len(all_links))
                    tr = False

        result_list = []

        for finale_link in all_links:    # Get data from all links
            driver.get(finale_link)
            time.sleep(3)


            try:
                id_info = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/main/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[3]/ul/li[1]/span')
                id_data = id_info.text
            except NoSuchElementException:
                id_data = ""

            try:
                title = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/main/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/h1')  # Find Elements
                title_data = title.text
            except NoSuchElementException:
                title_data = ""

            try:
                price = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/main/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[1]/p[1]')
                price_data = price.text
            except NoSuchElementException:
                price_data = ""

            try:
                area = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/main/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[1]/p[2]/span')
                area_data = area.text
            except NoSuchElementException:
                area_data = ""

            try:
                town = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/main/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[3]/ul/li[2]/span')
                town_data = town.text
            except NoSuchElementException:
                town_data = ""

            try:
                complex = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/main/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[3]/ul/li[3]/span')
                complex_data = complex.text
            except NoSuchElementException:
                complex_data = ""

            try:
                year = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/main/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[3]/ul/li[4]/span')
                year_data = year.text
            except NoSuchElementException:
                year_data = ""

            try:
                furniture = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/main/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[3]/ul/li[5]/span')
                furniture_data = furniture.text
            except NoSuchElementException:
                title_data = ""

            try:
                distance = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/main/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[3]/ul/li[6]/span')
                distance_data = distance.text
            except NoSuchElementException:
                title_data = ""

            try:
                look = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/main/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[3]/ul/li[7]/span')
                look_data = look.text
            except NoSuchElementException:
                look_data = ""

            try:
                season = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/main/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[3]/ul/li[8]/span')
                season_data = season.text
            except NoSuchElementException:
                season_data = ""

            try:
                floors = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/main/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[3]/ul/li[9]/span')
                floors_data = floors.text
            except NoSuchElementException:
                floors_data = ""

            try:
                material = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/main/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[3]/ul/li[10]/span')
                material_data = material.text
            except NoSuchElementException:
                material_data = ""

            try:
                heating = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/main/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[3]/ul/li[11]/span')
                heating_data = heating.text
            except NoSuchElementException:
                heating_data = ""

            try:
                parking = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/main/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[3]/ul/li[12]/span')
                parking_data = parking.text
            except NoSuchElementException:
                parking_data = ""

            try:
                guard = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/main/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[3]/ul/li[13]/span')
                guard_data = guard.text
            except NoSuchElementException:
                guard_data = ""

            try:
                elevator = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/main/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[3]/ul/li[14]/span')
                elevator_data = elevator.text
            except NoSuchElementException:
                elevator_data = "  "

            try:
                description = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/main/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[4]/p/span')
                description_data = description.text
            except NoSuchElementException:
                description_data = ""


            all_rooms = []
            try:
                rooms = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('/html/body/main/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/span[2]/span')
                for room in rooms:
                    room_data = room.text
                    all_rooms.append(room_data)
            except NoSuchElementException:
                all_rooms = ""

            time.sleep(3)
            try:
                coords = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="map"]')
                coords_data = coords.get_attribute("data-coords")
                #print(coords_data)
            except NoSuchElementException:
                coords_data = ""

            try:
                image_list = []
                base = finale_link
                rs = requests.get(base)
                root = BeautifulSoup(rs.content, 'html.parser')


                urls = root.select('#slider > li > img[src]')
                for url in urls:
                    images_data = (base + url['src'])
                    image_list.append(images_data)

            except NoSuchElementException:
                image_list = []



# ↓ Putting information in xml ↓  



            root1 = ElementTree.Element("items")
            item = ElementTree.SubElement(root1, "item")

            ads_id = ElementTree.SubElement(item, "id")
            ads_id.text = id_data

            title_x = ElementTree.SubElement(item, "title")
            title_x.text = title_data

            area_x = ElementTree.SubElement(item, "total_area")
            area_x.text = area_data

            price_x = ElementTree.SubElement(item, "price")
            price_x.text = price_data

            town_x = ElementTree.SubElement(item, "town")
            town_x.text = town_data

            complex_x = ElementTree.SubElement(item, "complex")
            complex_x.text = complex_data

            year_x = ElementTree.SubElement(item, "year")
            year_x.text = year_data

            furniture_x = ElementTree.SubElement(item, "furniture")
            furniture_x.text = furniture_data

            distance_x = ElementTree.SubElement(item, "distance")
            distance_x.text = distance_data

            look_x = ElementTree.SubElement(item, "look_at_wind")
            look_x.text = look_data

            season_x = ElementTree.SubElement(item, "season")
            season_x.text = season_data

            floors_x = ElementTree.SubElement(item, "floors")
            floors_x.text = floors_data

            material_x = ElementTree.SubElement(item, "material")
            material_x.text = material_data

            heating_x = ElementTree.SubElement(item, "heating")
            heating_x.text = heating_data

            parking_x = ElementTree.SubElement(item, "parking")
            parking_x.text = parking_data

            guard_x = ElementTree.SubElement(item, "guard")
            guard_x.text = guard_data

            rooms_x = ElementTree.SubElement(item, "rooms")
            rooms_x.text = room_data

            for room_a in all_rooms:
                room_xm = ElementTree.SubElement(rooms_x, "room")
                room_xm.text = room_a

            elevator_x = ElementTree.SubElement(item, "elevator")
            elevator_x.text = elevator_data

            description_x = ElementTree.SubElement(item, "description")
            description_x.text = description_data

            coords_x = ElementTree.SubElement(item, "coords")
            coords_x.text = coords_data

            images_x = ElementTree.SubElement(item, "images")

            for image_a in image_list:
                image_xm = ElementTree.SubElement(images_x, "image")
                image_xm.text = image_a

            tree = ElementTree.ElementTree(root1)
            tree.write("result_list.xml", encoding='utf-8')

            number += 1
            print("[+]", number, "//", len(all_links))

    except Exception as ex:
        raise ex

    finally:
        print("♥ Завершение работы ♥")
        driver.close()
        driver.quit()






def main():
    get_link_info()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: что-то не видно чтобы вы добавляли новый элемент в xml. Вы переписываете один и тот же. Создавайте новый элемент и добавляйте с помощью root1.append(новый элемент)

Comment: Вы каждый раз создаёте root1 и каждый раз перезаписываете файл. Вынесите из цикла эти действия. Одно до цикла, другое после.